# Alignment of icons to right overlaps with centrally aligned labels on checking responsiveness in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a webpage with certain tags (tags can be of `n` number) aligned centrally. I have three fixed icons (Smile, Heart and Star) aligned to right. It looks fine, but when I check for responsive layout (for mobile phones), then instead of coming down to next line, icons overlap with the tags. Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Health</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Fitness</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Safety</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="animated-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o faa-bounce fa-2x animated"></i></a> 30
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart faa-pulse animated"></i></a> 10
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star faa-vertical fa-2x animated"></i></a> 20
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="post-header" style="text-align: center">This is the header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

.faa-pulse.animated,
.faa-pulse.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover > .faa-pulse {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  font-size:1.8em;  
}
.fa-heart {
    color: red !important;
}
.fa-star {
    color: gold !important;
}
.fa-smile-o {
  color: deeppink !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 10%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 10%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

.faa-bounce.animated,
.faa-bounce.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover > .faa-bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  4% {
   -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  8% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  12% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  22% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}

@keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  4% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  8% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  12% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-3px);
    transform: translate(0,-3px);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,3px);
    transform: translate(0,3px);
  }

  22% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}

.faa-vertical.animated,
.faa-vertical.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover > .faa-vertical {
  -webkit-animation: vertical 2s ease infinite;
  animation: vertical 2s ease infinite;
}
.animated-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://www.bootply.com/iFGtO7DhfA)

Now when I try to check for responsive layout, the icons start overlapping with the tags "Health", "Fitness" and "Safety". What am I doing wrong? How to fix this issue?

Comment: So, at that specific breakpoint, use `media-query` and give a `margin-top` to your right `icons` and let it appear like in next line.

Comment: @DeepakYadav Ok I will try the same. But can you provide a working demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position` and make that `span` tag render as a `block` element or you can also use `margin` property. All this inside a `media-query`

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

.faa-pulse.animated,
.faa-pulse.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover>.faa-pulse {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.fa-heart {
  color: red !important;
}

.fa-star {
  color: gold !important;
}

.fa-smile-o {
  color: deeppink !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  10%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  10%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

.faa-bounce.animated,
.faa-bounce.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover>.faa-bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  4% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  8% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  12% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  22% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  4% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  8% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  12% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  16% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -3px);
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 3px);
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  22% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

.faa-vertical.animated,
.faa-vertical.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover>.faa-vertical {
  -webkit-animation: vertical 2s ease infinite;
  animation: vertical 2s ease infinite;
}

.animated-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 490px) {
  .animated-icons {
    position: static;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Health</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Fitness</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Safety</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="animated-icons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o faa-bounce fa-2x animated"></i></a> 30
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart faa-pulse animated"></i></a> 10
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star faa-vertical fa-2x animated"></i></a> 20
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="post-header" style="text-align: center">This is the header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following css for mobile view

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {    
    .animated-icons{
        position:relative
     }
}
```